# exception of strcpy function in c++ console program

Tags: c++, exception, strcpy

exception in strcpy();

```
void recid(string str,int *begin, int *end)
{
  char *f,*str2;

  const char c1[2]=":",c2[2]="-";
  strcpy(str2,str.c_str());
  f=strtok(str2,c1);
  f=strtok(NULL,c2);
  *begin=atoi(f);
  f=strtok(NULL,c2);
  *end=atoi(f);
}
```

could you help me to solve it?

Comment: What exception? Do you mean segfault? Also, why do you use C string functions with C++? That's usually a bad idea if you don't know what you are doing and *why*. And one problem is, str2 is uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Besides missing allocations, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c

Comment: Your question is throwing an exception of not showing the exception...

Answer (score 5):

`str2` is an uninitialised pointer.  `strcpy` does not allocate memory so is currently trying to write to an arbitrary address which you don't own and very likely isn't writable by your code.

You need to point `str2` to valid memory before calling `strcpy`.

```
str2 = (char*)malloc(str.size()+1);
strcpy(str2,str.c_str());
```

You should also `free` the memory later in your program

```
free(str2); // cannot dereference str2 after this point
```

Comment: thanks,but it will generate one error invalid conversion from void* to char*

Comment: @NadiaBarjaste I've updated my answer with the missing cast.  (I forgot the cast is required by C++; it isn't required and is discouraged in C)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you write in an uninitialized/random memory location by not initializing str2.

First solution:

```
str2 = new char[str.size() + 1];
strcpy(str2, str.c_str());
...
delete[] str2.
```

Second (better solution): Do not use pointers in your code unless you have to:

```
std::string str2 = str1;
```

Also, consider using std::ostringstream for tokenization into std::strings and converting to int.